Story where food reactivates dormant DNA
I'm trying to remember the title of a book I read in the UK, probably around 1990. One of the characters, an older man, underwent a major physical change to become stronger and possibly armoured in some way. I think this was in response to eating something so it may have been on another planet, but the idea was that something in what he ate interacted with 'junk DNA' in order to trigger the change.

Ringworld? The tree of life turns humans into Pak Protectors if they eat it.

Thanks @JohnRennie, this was the one

Possibly Larry Niven's Protector?
Alien grabs a human living in the outer solar system.  Human eats a special vegetable/root, then metamorphs into something very similar to the alien.
A background idea is that humans and the aliens are the same species, but Earth lacks the root, so we stay in the juvenile form.


Thank you - I believe this, and @JohnRennie's  comment are both correct
